# Dynamically add column to table and it's td's

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table that is already defined and populated. Now what I'm trying to do is to find a specific column and after that create a new column, at the moment I have the code to handle this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  something();
});

function something() {
  var newTh = "";
  var th = $(`#tblTable th[data-something="1"]`).last();
  newTh = `<th data-something="1-1">
                        New Column
                    </th>`;

  th.after(newTh);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th data-something="1">Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tblBody">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The column is added properly but it's keeping the value from the pre-existing column. What can I do to move the content after/before adding a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index of th element, and then you can find each tr to append **New Column** td value. Like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    something();
});

function something() {
    var newTh = "";
    var th = $(`#tblTable th[data-something="1"]`).last();
    var index = th.index();
    newTh = `<th data-something="1-1">New Column</th>`;

    th.after(newTh);

    $("#tblBody").find("tr").each(function(){
        var tr = $(this);
        tr.find("td").eq(index).after(`<td>new column value</td>`);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th data-something="1">Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tblBody">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to add another `<td>` in each `<tr>` and copy the text into the new `<td>`.

This works because each `<th>` must be at the same index as each `<tr>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  something();
});

function something() {
  const th = $('#tblTable th[data-something="1"]').last();
  th.after('<th data-something="1-1">New Column</th>');
  $('#tblTable tbody').children().each(function() {
    $(this).children().eq(th.index()).after('<tr></tr>');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th data-something="1">Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tblBody">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Having into consideration that maybe I'll have more than 10K rows, should I be worried about performance with this solution? I can handle 2-4sec but 10+ is not something acceptable

Comment: @User1899289003 I've updated my post to prevent unnecessary copying and simplify the code. It should run faster now, however I benchmarked it yet.